# cabal: haskell-gi-base refuses to install

Tags: haskell, cabal

When I try

```
$ cabal install gi-cairo
```

(One of the long list of dependencies to install leksah) I get the following error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring haskell-gi-base-0.9...
Building haskell-gi-base-0.9...
Failed to install haskell-gi-base-0.9
Build log ( /home/brandon/.cabal/logs/haskell-gi-base-0.9.log ):
Configuring haskell-gi-base-0.9...
Building haskell-gi-base-0.9...
Preprocessing library haskell-gi-base-0.9...

src/Data/GI/Base/Attributes.hs:105:8:
    Could not find module `Data.Proxy'
    It is a member of the hidden package `tagged-0.8.5'.
    Perhaps you need to add `tagged' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
gi-cairo-0.1.14.8 depends on haskell-gi-base-0.9 which failed to install.
haskell-gi-base-0.9 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I see the part about `tagged`, but where is this `.cabal` file ? On my machine it's a directory at `~/.cabal/`, not a file. And what do I add to this supposed file ?

By the way, the output of `cabal --version`:

```
cabal-install version 1.20.0.3
using version 1.20.0.2 of the Cabal library
```

My goal is to install the dependencies output by `leksah.sh` when I run it:

```
gi-cairo >=1.0.6 && <1.1,
gi-gdk >=3.0.6 && <3.1,
gi-gdkpixbuf >=2.0.6 && <2.1,
gi-gio >=2.0.6 && <2.1,
gi-glib >=2.0.6 && <2.1,
gi-gobject >=2.0.6 && <2.1,
gi-gtk >=3.0.6 && <3.1,
gi-gtk-hs >=0.3.1.0 && <0.4,
gi-gtksource >=3.0.6 && <3.1,
gi-pango >=1.0.6 && <1.1,
gi-webkit2 >=4.0.6 && <4.1,
haskell-gi-base >=0.18 && <0.21,
haskell-src-exts >=1.13.5 && <1.19,
leksah-server >=0.16.1.0 && <0.17,
ltk >=0.16.0.0 && <0.17,
regex-tdfa >=1.1 && <1.3,
regex-tdfa-text -any,
vcsgui >=0.2.0 && <0.3
```

I've been trying to solve this since last night, but I don't see anything like this documented anywhere when I Google.

---

UPDATE: When I try running `cabal install leksah`, I get the following errors:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: leksah-0.15.2.0 (user goal)
trying: vcswrapper-0.1.1/installed-1eQ... (dependency of leksah-0.15.2.0)
next goal: transformers (dependency of leksah-0.15.2.0)
rejecting: transformers-0.5.2.0/installed-3Es... (conflict: leksah =>
transformers>=0.2.2.0 && <0.5)
rejecting: transformers-0.3.0.0/installed-ff2... (conflict:
transformers-compat-0.5.1.4:three => transformers>=0.4.1 && <0.6)
rejecting: transformers-0.5.2.0, 0.5.1.0, 0.5.0.1, 0.5.0.0 (conflict: leksah
=> transformers>=0.2.2.0 && <0.5)
trying: transformers-0.4.3.0
next goal: mtl (dependency of leksah-0.15.2.0)
rejecting: mtl-2.2.1/installed-4vs... (conflict: transformers==0.4.3.0, mtl =>
transformers==0.5.2.0/installed-3Es...)
rejecting: mtl-2.1.2/installed-94c..., 2.2.1, 2.2.0.1, 2.2, 2.1.3.1, 2.1.2,
2.1.1, 2.1, 2.0.1.1, 2.0.1.0, 2.0.0.0, 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.0, 1.1.0.2, 1.1.0.1,
1.1.0.0, 1.0 (conflict: vcswrapper => mtl==2.2.1/installed-4vs...)
Backjump limit reached (change with --max-backjumps).
```

So I tried `cabal install leksah --max-backjumps -1` per the manpage of cabal and after about 10 minutes it's now consuming >40% of the memory of my machine, so I simply can't continue on that route.

Comment: Something is inconsistent between the environments in which you are running these commands - you say that `leksah.sh` demands `haskell-gi-base >=0.18 && <0.21` but `cabal` very clearly tells you it is installing `haskell-gi-base-0.9`. `cabal install leksah` should find the correct dependencies - trying to install them one by one is the wrong thing to do. The `cabal` file referred to in the error is the `cabal` file of `haskell-gi-base-0.9` - this version is probably just too old to be built with your configuration (cabal 1.20.0.3 is fairly new).

Comment: maybe you have more luck with [stack](https://www.haskellstack.org/)...

Comment: @user2407038 I've posted an update regarding your suggestion.

Comment: Your update suggests you are in dependency hell. Purge your package db and start anew, or use `stack` or at the very least a cabal sandbox. Also, if you get `cabal install` to make a working build plan (with `--max-backjumps` or any other flag) but that build plan takes 'too long' (10 minutes is too long?) there is no reason to expect that *any* build plan would be substantially faster - if the use of such resources for compilation in unacceptable to you, I'm afraid you simply will not be able to build leksah from source.

Comment: @user2407038 It's not that 10 minutes is too long, it's that after *only* 10 minutes it's consuming almost half my memory, and that's only climbing, which *is* unacceptable. I'm now trying Stack and it seems to be working well.

Answer (score 0):

The `Data.Proxy` module moved to the `base` package in `base-4.7.0.0` which was part of the `ghc-7.6` series. The `haskell-gi-base` you are trying to install is also quite old. I expect that it was selected because the newest version that could satisfy the version constraints, but that those version constraints are wrong. Your version of GHC must be older than this.

The solution is to update your GHC and cabal-install. Current version of GHC 8.0.2 and the current version of cabal-install is 1.24.0.2. You need at least version 1.24 of cabal-install when you upgrade to GHC 8. Fortunately the Minimal Haskell Platform comes with an up-to-date GHC, cabal-install, and even stack!